# Where would a mezuzah go on a completely round doorway?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, architecture-design

I’ve recently come across the site of a construction company
making houses modeled after hobbit holes.
I don’t know how this company is going to shape the doorways,
but the image below is how they’re described
in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*.

Can a *mezuzah* be affixed to such a completely round doorway,
or does this not have a “side” where a *mezuzah* belongs?

[image: Picture of Bag End with a round door, typical of Hobbit-houses]

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=11b&format=pdf

Comment: Does that imply no _mezuzah_, @DoubleAA?

Comment: _Probably_ but there are many ways the Rishonim interpret the exact case there.

Comment: If the size of the circle is big enough so that within 4 horizontal fist lengths there are walls (side posts) 10 vertical fist lengths then it requires a mezuza (costumerealy put on the bottom of the top 1/3rd of the vertical length within the 4 horizontl fist lengths)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mor U'Ketziya Orach Chaim 21 - right side - column beginning  ואין זו תשובה נצחת](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7920&st=&pgnum=40&hilite=) says that a door made like a Kippa does not require a Mezuza. [Pischei Shearim - page 238](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9708&st=&pgnum=238&hilite=) mentions that even if a doorway is rounded from the bottom there are those that say it does not require a Mezuza. Thus there are those who would say a completely round doorway would not require a Mezuza.

Comment: Based on DoubleAA's edit, your answer is now incomplete. If this is merely "there are those who would say," and if R' Ya'akov Emden's opinion is not necessarily *halacha p'suka*, then where would the (implied) other opinions say to place the *m'zuza*? If your answer is meant to definitively say that a round doorway does not require a *m'zuza*, you should rollback the previous edit and preferably explain in a bit more detail how you know this is *halacha p'suka*.